# Function on all sets

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Suppose we want to define function $c$, such that it takes some set $A$ and returns it's cardinality, that is $c(A) = |A|$.

One would be tempted to denote it, for instance, as $c: \Omega \to C_d$, where $\Omega$ is set of all sets and $C_d$ is set of cardinal numbers. But such $\Omega$ does not exist. Can therefore no function operate on any set?

Another example of such function could be a function, which takes a set and returns it's intersection with $\mathbb{R}$ - $f: \Omega \to 2^\mathbb{R}$.

Could anyone elaborate on this? Thanks

Comment: Note that $C_d$ also isn't a set.

Comment: you would need $c$ to be a class function

Comment: It depends on what system of set theory you are working in. In ZF set theory, the answer is no. In systems like NBG or MKM (google with "set theory" to find references), there are class functions such as your $c$ and $f$. Note that $f$ is of little interest from an ordinary mathematical perspective since it is dependent on the choice of one of many equivalents ways of defining the real numbers.

Comment: You can’t define it as an internal function. You can define it as a shorthand. Just as there are set-theory internal  relations, defined as subsets of $A\times B$  where $A,B$ are sets, their are first order relations like membership: $a\in b.$ The most common such functional notation is $\mathcal P(A)$ for the power set of $A.$ $\mathcal P$ is not a function, but we use functional notation.

Comment: Well, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Class_(set_theory)#Classes_in_formal_set_theories says "In ZF, the concept of a function can also be generalised to classes. A class function is not a function in the usual sense, since it is not a set; it is rather a formula  (x ,y) with the property that for any set x  there is no more than one set y  such that the pair (x ,y)  satisfies Φ  For example, the class function mapping each set to its successor may be expressed as the formula y = x∪{ x } . The fact that the ordered pair (x , y) satisfies Φ may be expressed with the shorthand notation Φ(x ) = y"

Comment: ... which addresses exactly what you are trying to do.   .... tl/dr.... just do it but don't call it a "function".